# Better of or better off?

Tags: phrases

Which of the following two phrases correct: "I expect better of you" or "I expect better off you"?

Comment: *I expect better off you* is not an idiom I have ever heard.

Comment: Neither had I.  It was a correction I received from a British English speaker.

Comment: @TrixieG. Perhaps a British English speaker with one of their many obscure regional accents? Unless he's just tried to steal your watch, and found it to be a lower quality item than the rest of your apparel suggests.

Comment: @TrixieG. Were you corrected in the same context as posed in your question? "Better off" is a fine combination of words in certain situations, though not in this case.

Comment: Are you sure the word in question is `off` rather than `of` as spoken with an accent and/or speech impediment? (@WayfaringStranger, that's awesome: *"Your wallet's empty! I expected better off you!"*)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "I expect you to do better", then "better of you" is correct.

Usually, "better off" describes the outcome of a situation. For example: "you would be better off if you stopped working now and get some sleep" or "we are better off not knowing how the sausage gets made."

Answer (score 1):

While both are grammatically correct, I've only ever heard "better of" in this context.

I can maybe think of an example where "better off" would be correct. Perhaps if I picked your pocket and only found Monopoly money, I might then say "I expect better off you", but that's a pretty huge stretch.

The simplest explanation is that whoever corrected you was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

(a) "I expect better of you" the usual phrase.

(b) "I expect better from you" a valid alternative to (a)

(c) "I expect better off you" a substandard or possibly regional version